# A ton of Event ID 10009 on a SBS 2011 Server

Tags: windows-sbs

[image]A lot of threads just say to ignore them or turn them off but I have a feeling there is really something going on. It is a SBS 2011 Server and Windows 10 Professional workstations. Massive event id 10009 and a few event id 4 on the server. I turned the firewalls off on the workstations. Screen shots of the errors are attach. Any Ideas?

[EventID 10009](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYzpi.png)

Comment: These events identify a client workstation. Has anything been changed on the client system(s). Do the entries in DNS for the clients have correct data? Are any relevant events logged on the client systems?

Comment: The first question I have, are you even using, Kerberos?  This specifc event indicates a NTP problem.  Before I could provide any specifc resolution, you would have to confirm that the client and the server both agree it's the same time.

Comment: Nothing has been changed on the clients but  I am not sure how long these errors have been going on. The DNS entries should be correct. I look through them and deleted the ones that weren't correct and then scavenged. No relevant log entries on the client. I just checked the time on the server and a time on one of the clients and it is identical. Have disabled the firewall on the clients and server. Don't know if I am using Kerberos or not. It is a default installation. I have read a lot about this issue and never seen a reference to a NTP issue. What makes you believe it is a NTP issue?

Comment: Have a look at the entry *DCOM Event ID 10009* in this [MSKB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/957713/windows-sbs-2008-known-post-installation-event-errors) (it applies to SBS 2011 as well).